# How to create value pairs with lambda in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark

I am trying to convert a pyspark rdd like this:

before:

```
[
    [('169', '5'), ('2471', '6'), ('48516', '10')], 
    [('58', '7'), ('163', '7')], 
    [('172', '5'), ('186', '4'), ('236', '6')]
]
```

after:

```
[ 
    [('169', '5'), ('2471', '6')],
    [('169', '5'),('48516', '10')],
    [('2471', '6'), ('48516', '10')],
    [('58', '7'), ('163', '7')],
    [('172', '5'), ('186', '4')],
    [('172', '5'), ('236', '6')],
    [('186', '4'), ('236', '6')]
]
```

The idea is to go through each line and create new line pairwise. I tried to find out a solution myself with `lambda` tutorials but with no good. May I ask for some help? If this is repeating other questions, I apologize. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `flatMap` with `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

rdd.flatMap(lambda xs: combinations(xs, 2))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks!